# HtmlUnit: HtmlPage Serialization Exception

Tags: javascript, css, htmlunit, serializable

After executing a JavaScript function that injects a style attribute on a HTML tag using HtmlUnit-2.13, we cannot serialize the resultant HtmlPage and we receive the following error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException:com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleDeclaration$StyleElement
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
```

If the style attribute is on the Page and not injected, the page can be serialized without any problem.

**Updated on 12/04/2013:**
I found the problem to be located at this field:

> *private Map<String, StyleElement> styleMap_*;

which is member of the CSSStyleDeclaration class. The StyleElement class does not implement the Serializable interface.

Initially, the field equals to null and no problem occurs. However, once a JavaScript event is executed, the Map does not longer point to null and the exception is being thrown.

Am I doing something wrong ? This field is supposed to be always null or nobody has tried to serialize that class before ?

Comment: How exactly are you serializing the page?

Comment: I use the following snippet:
`ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;

try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  out.writeObject(page);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
finally {
  out.close();
  bos.close();
}
return bos.toByteArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I created a bug, and it's fixed now: https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1569/
So you can use latest build from their SVN and it works fine!